# string class disposable method

Tags: c#

```
private void test()
{
    string tst = null;
    try
    {
        tst = "abc";     
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        tst = null;           
    }
}
```

My query is - Is it meaningful to type `tst = null;` in the finally block as the string class doesn't have the disposable method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `string` implemented `IDisposable`, setting a variable to null wouldn't call the `Dispose` method. It's utterly pointless, as is the catch block with the throw.

If you see code like this in a codebase you're maintaining, rip it out and have a quiet word with whoever put it in there in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have any effect, as `tst` goes out of scope immediately after the `finally`.
And this has nothing to do with `Dispose`.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not necessary. The variable `tst` does no longer exists, when `test()` returns.